# MySQL data not outputting onto bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am attempting to output data onto my modal but nothing appears. I have managed to output some of my data on my created table. However, when attempting to bring up further data through the modal nothing seems to appear.

I have been chopping through the PHP for potential fixes, but no luck.

The php below is meant to output the data onto the modal after receiving information from my `news.php` file:

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST["employee_id"]))  
{  
  $output = '';  
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "test1234", "news_db");  
  $query = "SELECT * FROM latest_news WHERE news_id = '".$_POST["employee_id"]."'";  
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
  $output .= '  
  <div class="table-responsive">  
      <table class="table table-bordered">';  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  { 
    $output .= '  
     <tr>  
      <td width="30%"><label>Name</label></td>  
       <td width="70%">'.$row["news_title"].'</td>  
      </tr> 
      <tr>  
        <td width="30%"><label>Address</label></td>  
        <td width="70%">'.$row["news_text"].'</td>  
        </tr>  
    ';  
  } 
  $output .= "</table></div>";  
  echo $output;  
}  
?>
```

This table from my news.php file successfully outputs the required data from my table:

```
<div class="table-responsive">  
  <table class="table table-bordered">  
    <tr>  
      <th width="70%">Employee Name</th>  
      <th width="30%">View</th>  
    </tr>  
    <?php  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
    ?>  
      <tr>  
        <td><?php echo $row["news_title"]; ?></td>  
        <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $row["news_id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
      </tr>  
    <?php  
    }  
    ?>  
  </table>  
</div>  

<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
  <div class="modal-dialog">  
    <div class="modal-content">  
      <div class="modal-header">  
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
        <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Details</h4>  
      </div>  
      <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail"></div>  
      <div class="modal-footer">  
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
       </div>  
     </div>  
   </div>  
 </div>
```

**Modal script:**

```
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
   $('.view_data').click(function(){  
     var employee_id = $(this).attr("news_id");  
     $.ajax({  
       url:"select.php",  
       method:"post",  
       data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
       success:function(data){  
         $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
         $('#dataModal').modal("show");  
       }  
     });  
   });  
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: non displaying data is the least of your worries, you should be researching first how to prevent SQl injections..

Comment: Something I'm already mitigating, made simpler by the fact user input won't be required @RaymondNijland

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems OK, but are you sure the SQL query you are using is right?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM latest_news WHERE news_id = '".$_POST["employee_id"]."'";
```

you're using `employee_id` as `news_id`. that may be the problem. try getting the `$query` value and run it on your database.

---

By the way, consider using PDO and prepared statements on your PHP scritps. `filter_input()` can also help making your code more secure